# Magento header module not showing properly

Tags: layout, header

I created a new layout and assign it to my home page.The layout working fine,Here is my local.xml file.

```
  <page_home_layout translate="label">
        <label> Layout Home Page</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/home.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
            <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>Home Page</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="header">
           <block type="youama_slider/slider" name="youamaslider" template="youama/slider/slider.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
       </reference>
```

**My problem is** The module youamaslider is not showing in header,It is showing after the footer.Is there anything wrong i have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try using static block placing this code

`{{block type="youama_slider/slider" name="youamaslider" alias="youamaslider" template="youama/slider/slider.phtml"}}` in a `static block` and call it in this way

```
<reference name="header">
  <block type="cms/block" name="youamaslider">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>youamaslider</block_id></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Its not a cms block

Comment: I told you to try using CMS block